# Выбрать все email из текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Доброго времени суток! Есть тривиальная задача - выбрать все адреса почты из текста. Проблема в том, что я не хочу писать `preg_match_all`, так как регулярка будет очень большой. Сейчас у меня такой код:

```
array_walk($arr = preg_split('/\s/', $text), function($val, $key){

    //так делать нельзя, но если очень хочется, то можно  
    global $arr;

    if(!filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
});
```

как его можно оптимизировать?

Comment: Если брать в простом смысле email, то всё очень просто и в две строчки: код на [ideone.com][1], а если брать [сложную][2] регулярку, то да, будет много букв.

[1]: http://ideone.com/ENqdMk
[2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/719543/1587107

Comment: тот случай, когда много букв. Значит мой вариант не такой уж костыль?

Comment: у вас проблема не столько в фильтре, сколько в сплите.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как насчет того огромного шаблона на мыло, - этого вполне должно хватить. И при всем вашем отказе от **preg_match_all**, такой вариант мне кажется самым подходящим.

```
$mail = <<<EMAIL
    Мой тестовый текст, для того, что бы проверять и ловить по регулярному выражению email-ы
    Допустим тут будет мой емейл: mymail@gmail.com, а тут будет эмейл моего друга: myfriend@mail.ru.
    Еще, предположу, что тут будет email моей мамы: i_love_my_mam@yandex.ru и моего папы: i_love_my_father_to@rambler.ru
    Мыло брата и сестры: brother-mail@mail.vv.si, sister-mail@mail.vv.si
    EMAIL;

$mail2 = <<<EMAIL2
Отловит, например, super.user@e.mail, или user2@e.mail, или user@e1.mail. И не навалит много мусора, например, часто встречающееся в конце предложения "пиши мне на klopp@yandex.ru." (с точкой в конце), не говоря о тех же точках: после собаки, сдвоенных точках, и много другого мусора.
EMAIL2;

    $arr = array();
    $ptrn = "/\b([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+)\b/i"; //вот мой маленький да удаленький шаблончик )
    preg_match_all($ptrn,$mail,$arr);

    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($arr[0]);
    echo("</pre>");
```

**Итог**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mymail@gmail.com
    [1] => myfriend@mail.ru
    [2] => i_love_my_mam@yandex.ru
    [3] => i_love_my_father_to@rambler.ru
    [4] => brother-mail@mail.vv.si
    [5] => sister-mail@mail.vv.si
)
```

**Итог EMAIL2**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => super.user@e.mail
    [1] => user2@e.mail
    [2] => user@e1.mail
    [3] => klopp@yandex.ru
)
```

Comment: >//вот мой маленький да удаленький шаблончик

который ой как много не отловит... или отловит некорректно.

Comment: А точнее? Мне интересно какой реальный, валидный мейл, он не отловит?

Comment: Не отловит, например, `super.user@e.mail`, или `user2@e.mail`, или `user@e1.mail`. Зато навалит много мусора, например, часто встречающееся в конце предложения "`пиши мне на klopp@yandex.ru.`" (с точкой в конце), не говоря о тех же точках: после собаки, сдвоенных точках, и много другого мусора. Не зря всё-таки умные люди тот "длинный непонятный" регексп писали, он отлажен десятилетиями, миллионами случаев использования и точно соответствует RFC.

Comment: Точка в конце не страшна, но Я внес некоторые изменения (в 1вом подборе добавил точку и цифры). Спс ) Изменения влепил сверху )

Comment: Ну до чего же любят некоторые люди изобретать свои велосипеды и ходить по своим граблям :) И на этот вариант можно найти провалы, и на следующий найдутся... С другой стороны, может хоть так дело дойдёт до чтения RFC :-)

Comment: Еще одно маленько изменение во 2ром подборе (добавит цифры))
@klopp, Нет ничего идеального. Для этого и есть Мы: что бы заклеивать эти провалы ) 

Понемногу буду пытаться читать RFC )

Comment: Так смысл использовать уже готовые и отлаженные библиотеки в том и состоит, чтобы не тратить время на решение проблем, которые уже давно решены.

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется оптимизировать процесс валидации, то в первую очередь нужно отказаться от цикла и сделать все в одном `preg_match_all`, потому что практика показывает, что в скриптовых языках сделать один вызов нативной "тяжелой" функции производительнее, чем в цикле применять "легкие" функции.

Представьте, что у Вас в тексте 10000 слов и Вы разбили текст по пробелам и потом в цикле применяете к каждому слову фильтр.

Обратимся к исходниками реализации `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` :
[GitHub: PHP-src logical_filters](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L601)
Там мы увидим вот такое регулярное выражение:

```
/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/iD
```

Его авторство принадлежит Michael Rushton и почитать про него можно в [блоге](http://squiloople.com/2009/12/20/email-address-validation/).

Теперь нам ничто не мешает заменить повсеместно в этом регулярном выражении знак `^` на `(?:\\s|^)` , а `$` на `(?:\\s|$)` и выполнить всего один `preg_match_all`. Ах да, и не перепутайте знак начала строки с знаком отрицания символьного класса `[^...]`.

Это самый производительный путь.

---

Если не хочется видеть в своем коде такое "страшное" регулярное выражение, то оптимизации можно достичь попробовав поискать сначала что-то похожее на e-mail, а уж потом применить к нему полноценный фильтр.

```
preg_match_all( "/[^@\s]++@\S++/", $text, $result );
```

Теперь можно в цикле перебирать результат.

Вы будете негодовать

> и чем этот вариант лучше моего?

Все очень просто - это регулярное выражение наиболее производительно, а вопрос стоит как раз про производительность.

Comment: Увы, такой вариант будет пропускать часть писем. Покажу на примере. Допустим есть строка:
`"user1@example.net, user2@example.net; user3@example.net"`
После того, как мы прогоняем эту строку через предложенную функцию
`preg_match_all( "/[^@\s]++@\S++/", $text, $result);`
мы получаем массив $result:
`['user1@example.net,', 'user2@example.net;', 'user3@example.net']`
Теперь, когда мы перебираем найденные варианты и прогоняем их через filter_var() - первые два адреса отсеются, поскольку у них на конце запятая и они не валидны. А я хотел отправить на них письма.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранить использование встроенного фильтра. Пример на **[ideone.com](http://ideone.com/yoHcZO)**

```
<?php
$text = '
some@email.com
not_email@test another@junk email@again.com
@var notvar@

some random text
';

$pattern = '~[^\s]+@[^\s]+~';
$output = array();

//Захватываем все выражения, похожие на e-mail
preg_match_all($pattern, trim($text), $matches);

//Отсеиваем лишнее
foreach($matches[0] as $key => $val) {
    $email = filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if($email) {
        $output[] = $email;
    }   
}

print_r($output);
```

Выведет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => some@email.com
    [1] => email@again.com
)
```

Comment: и чем этот вариант лучше моего?

Comment: Не использует **global**?